# How do we eager fetch content fields from the Orchard CMS Queries user interface

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

When using the Orchard UI to create queries, how do we eager fetch fields? For instance, we have a content type that has an input field, link field, media library picker field, date time field, and text field. None of these fields are terribly complex. **How do we eager load fields from the UI?**  I've looked at the Eager Load filter, and based on intuition, have considered eager loading the `FieldIndexPartRecord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to: fields are stored in the Infoset, which is a XML data blob stored on the content item's record. Therefore, it is *always* eager-fetched. Do you have profile data indicating otherwise?

Comment: Todo: Use Mini Profiler.